# Use multiple ReportItems in one expression in RDLC Report

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc

I want to display page wise sum of 2 columns in footer.for that I am using following expression in footer

```
=Sum(ReportItems!col1.Value) + Sum(ReportItems!col2.Value)
```

but it gives following error

"**The Value expression for the textrun refers to more than one report item.  An expression in a page header or footer can refer to only one report item.**"

anybody knows how can I solve this issue and display page wise sum in footer ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is simple workaround for your problem:

1. Add single textbox to the body of the report and name it i.e. "SUM"
2. Add your expression to this textbox `=ReportItems!col1.Value + ReportItems!col2.Value`
3. For this textbox set visibility as hidden
4. In the footer refer to this hidden textbox using `=ReportItems!SUM.Value`

Comment: don't work.it gives following error   "The Value expression for the text box ‘SUM’ refers to the report item ‘col1’.  Report item expressions can only refer to other report items within the same grouping scope or a containing grouping scope."   AND

"The Value expression for the textrun 'SUM.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]' uses an aggregate function on a report item.  Aggregate functions can be used only on report items contained in page headers and footers.
"

Comment: I forgot about removing "sum" aggregate. Modify expression removing sum. It should look like follows: =ReportItems!col1.Value + ReportItems!col2.Value

Comment: still it gives error "The Value expression for the text box ‘SUM’ refers to the report item ‘col1’. Report item expressions can only refer to other report items within the same grouping scope or a containing grouping scope".

Comment: Is "col1" textbox included into any group? If so try to add total value under this group and then refer to the total value textbox instead of "col1" textbox.

Comment: not it is not belong to any group.I just put it outside the tablix.

Comment: Please attach screen of your report in design mode and point col1 and col2 columns.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use Custom code-feature of report for these operations. Just open Report Properties and choose Code-view. Just then write basic VB get/set-methods to save and sum values.
Referring to methods in TextBox expression goes just like this: =Code.[YourMethodNameHere]. 
For example, saving value:

```
=Code.SaveMyValue(Fields!MyVal.Value)
```

and getting value:

```
=Code.GetMyValue()
```