# sum total of column in rdlc report footer

Tags: c#, aggregate-functions, rdlc

I have dataset1 contains : ( name - price ) in rdlc report and textbox1 placed in the footer of the report. I tried to sum the total of column (price) but I get error :

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error
>   The Value expression for the text box ‘Textbox1’ references
>   report item 'price' in an aggregate expression with a scope.  A scope
>   is not allowed on aggregates in the page header or footer which
>   reference report items

here is the expression I used :

```
=SUM(reportitems!price.Value, "dataset1")
```

how to sum the column price and show the result in textbox1 in the footer ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reference report Datasource in the footer of the report. But you can reference report item (only one). So, you have three options:

- do not show in report footer, instead show it in table footer
- show it in table footer (but make it "white on white", no invisible) and reference value of that textbox in the report footer:

= ReportItems!textBoxTotalName.Value

- use Custom Code function to calculate your total. See here: [Use multiple ReportItems in one expression in RDLC Report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20898506/use-multiple-reportitems-in-one-expression-in-rdlc-report)

Comment: can you show me how to create the VB function in custom code

Comment: You really should try to search for existing answers too. Here are good examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29537886/adding-multiple-functions-to-rdlc-custom-code